# How to stop execution of a Firebase-triggered Firebase Function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

**Background**

As to my knowledge, Firebase-triggered functions can run more than once from just one triggering event (I think I can see that from the logs in Firebase).

Since this is potentially a data-corrupting behavior, I would like to implement some flag, which allows the function to stop if it finds that the flag is `true`.

Upon creation of that object in the database I would like this function (Typescript) to run only once.

For example:

```
adm.database().ref('/Users/{UserID}')
```

I plan to store a key value pair for each user node in the database:

```
{"alreadyTriggered":true}
```

Or store the 'trigger' in a separate node, it does not matter.

And then when Firebase decides to trigger the respective function, I will do a check and stop the execution of the function if it is not the first time it is being run:

```
data = snapshot.val();
if (data.alreadyTriggered) {
    return;
}
// The function continues here
```

**Implementation**

(some parentheses and brackets can be missing, it's a psecudocode-Typescript written in the browser window)

index.ts:

```
    import * as u from './users';
    import * as ff from 'firebase-functions';
    import * as adm from 'firebase-admin';
    import * as types from './types';

    // Triggered function
    export const userCreated = ff.database.ref('/Users/{userId}').onCreate((sn, ctx) => {
      let user: types.User = sn.val();
      console.log(`New user created, User Id: ${ctx.params.userId}`);
      return u.onCreated(user);
    });
```

users.ts:

```
// Function implementation

export function onCreated(user: types.User): Promise<void> {
    return adm.database().ref("/Triggers").once('value', snapshot => {
        let data: any = snapshot.val();
        const alreadyTriggered: boolean = data.alreadyTriggered; 
    }).then(alreadyTriggered => {
        if (alreadyTriggered) {
            // We would like to stop any execution here
            return
        }
        else {
            console.log(`Continuing processing`)
        }
    }).then(() => {
        // This code should be reached only if alreadyTriggered is set to false
        // do actual work with the user object
        //...someNewData
        //then save it
        adm.database().ref('/Users').child(user.userId).update(someNewData)
    })
}
```

**Problem**

The problem is that is that I don't know how reliably to stop executing the function. I have tried to use `return` (doesn't work), `break` (only for loops) and I came to using `throw new Error('Stopping function execution')`, but it does not seem to stop reliably - sometimes I see in the logs that the function *does* continue the execution although `alreadyTriggered` is definitely `true`.

**Question**

How can I stop execution of a Firebase Typescript function from within its code?

Comment: Please read the part of the documentation that talks about [idempotence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#write_idempotent_functions).  You will need a strategy for implementing idempotence, but there are many ways to do this, depending on the needs of your function. What you've shown here isn't enough information to tell what's required, or what you've tried that isn't working the way you expect.  Consider showing the *entire* function that's not working, not just a few lines.

Comment: Doug, thanks a lot for the comment. I have read the documentation on idempotence, but the only hint about stopping I could find is calling some Node callback, which I could not find about. I have provided the entire function as per your advice, thanks!

Comment: I have watched the video about idempotence (the link you provided), thank you. However, it it describes a strategy of avoiding running the _same_instance_of_the_same_function more than once (through the context), but I would like to make sure that even if it's different invocations of the same function, I stop all the other invocations if one is running already. So far I was able to reliably stop it by returning `return Promise.reject("Stopping")`, but I am not sure this is an elegant solution.

Comment: You will have to store some data in a database or other persistent storage that the other invocations can check in order to prevent the function from completing.

Comment: Yes, that is what for I use `/Triggers` and check the `alreadyTriggered` value. But once the function finds out it's `true` - how do I stop the execution of of the other code in the function?

Answer (score 2):

Your `return` statement isn't returning from the top-level function.  It's just returning from the lambda function you passed to `then()`.  You will have to propagate information down the chain of promises to tell the next callback whether or not to do its work.

```
return adm.database().ref("/Triggers").once('value', snapshot => {
    let data: any = snapshot.val();
    const alreadyTriggered: boolean = data.alreadyTriggered; 
}).then(alreadyTriggered => {
    if (alreadyTriggered) {
        // We would like to stop any execution here
        return false
    }
    else {
        console.log(`Continuing processing`)
        return true
    }
}).then((continue) => {
    // This code should be reached only if alreadyTriggered is set to false
    // do actual work with the user object
    //...someNewData
    //then save it
    if (continue) {
        return adm.database().ref('/Users').child(user.userId).update(someNewData)
    }
})
```

You also missed a return of the promise returned by `update` above, which would cause your function to time out.

Note that this is all lot easier with async/await syntax.

Comment: Why can't we run the last `.then` without any parameter to the successful callback? I.e. run `.then( => { //do actual work...` instead of `.then((continue) =>`? To stop or not to stop was taken care on the previous step. Or `return false` just provides `false` to the next `.then`? I am not sure what `return false` actually does.

Comment: Also, I thought that chaining multiple `then`s is the good practice for Firebase Functions. Could you please refer to some good example on how async/await syntax is better in such a case? Thx